Prevent line break when using pmatrix within an equation
I'm trying to write a matrix equation using the pmatrix environment. I'd like it to be of the form:
matrix  matrix = matrix
all in one line.
However, when I compile my code (minimum working example below), I get something like:
matrix
matrix
=
matrix
How can I have all three of my matricies in a single line (they are all 2x2 and should easiliy fit).
Code:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, mathtools, amsthm, amssymb}

\begin{document}

This is my matrix equation:

\begin{equation*}

  \begin{pmatrix}
    \frac{\partial x}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial v} \\
    \frac{\partial y}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial v} \\
  \end{pmatrix}
  
  \begin{pmatrix}
    \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \\
    \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} \\
  \end{pmatrix}

  =
  
  \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 \\ 
    0 & 1 \\
  \end{pmatrix}

\end{equation*}

\end{document}


Off-topic: \usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, mathtools, amsthm, amssymb} may be shortened to just \usepackage{mathtools, amsthm, amssymb}, as mathtools  loads amsmath,  while amssym loads amsfonts.

The moral of the answer is that if you have any errors in your code, you have to resolve those before you can worry about the output.  Any output you may get is only a guide to help resolve the errors.

The input shown produces errors, not a usable output
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.9 
    
? 
! Display math should end with $$.
<to be read again> 
                   \tex_par:D 
l.9 
    
?

Blank lines are not allowed in math mode.  equation* is always a single line display so you do not need to do anything to prevent a line break.

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, mathtools, amsthm, amssymb}

\begin{document}

This is my matrix equation:

\begin{equation*}
  \begin{pmatrix}
    \frac{\partial x}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial v} \\
    \frac{\partial y}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial v} \\
  \end{pmatrix}
  \begin{pmatrix}
    \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \\
    \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} \\
  \end{pmatrix}
  =
  \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 \\ 
    0 & 1 \\
  \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}

